# Passing a TStrings Object to a Secondary Thread in Delphi

Tags: multithreading, delphi, winapi, tstringlist

I'd like to know how to pass the local object address of a `TStrings` object (allocated on the heap, IIRC) from the calling function to a thread I create with `CreateThread()`. The thread has an infinite wait, so the object should still be available at the caller level, waiting to be filled with information.

I'd like to keep this Win32 related and not use the VCL `TThread` class for such stuff.

Does anyone have an example of how to do this? `IsMutliThread` is already set to `True` before the `CreateThread()` API call. I just would like to utilize passing the address of the `TStrings` variable directly to the worker thread.

Comment: You probably don't want to pass the address of the variable, but the pointer to the `TStrings` object itself.

Comment: Do you have an example of this? I know what you mean but clarity would be helpful otherwise I may land an Abstract Error or something like that upon access in the worker thread.

Comment: Given `var S: TStrings`, you don't want to pass `Pointer(@S)` but `Pointer(S)`.

Comment: "*otherwise I may land an Abstract Error or something like that*" - No, you will not.

Comment: In general, this isn't possible. Because if all you have is TStrings then you don't know anything about its thread affinity. The TStrings from a TListbox has affinity to the GUI thread. But a TStringList would be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, `IsMutliThread` has no effect on `CreateThread()`.

Second, `CreateThread()` has an `lpParameter` parameter for this exact kind of situation.  It is an untyped `Pointer`, so you can pass whatever you want to your thread function.  In this case, you can simply pass the *value* of the `TStrings` local variable, you don't need to pass the *address* of the local variable, eg:

```pascal
function MyThreadProc(lpParameter: Pointer): DWORD; stdcall;
var
  List: TStrings;
begin
  List := TStrings(lpParameter);
  // populate List as needed...
  Result := 0;
end;

...

var
  List: TStrings;
  H: THandle;
  TID: DWORD;
begin
  List := TStringList.Create;
  try
    H := CreateThread(nil, 0, @MyThreadProc, List, 0, TID);
    if H = 0 then RaiseLastOSError;
    WaitForSingleObject(H, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(H);
    // use List as needed...
  finally
    List.Free;
  end;
end;
```

That being said, creating a worker thread just to immediately wait for it to terminate is a *waste* of a worker thread.  In which case, you may as well just remove the worker thread altogether and call the thread function directly and wait for it to return, the end result will be exactly the same - the caller waits until the `TStrings` is populated - eg:

```
procedure MyProc(List: TStrings);
begin
  // populate List as needed...
end;

...

var
  List: TStrings;
begin
  List := TStringList.Create;
  try
    MyProc(List);
    // use List as needed...
  finally
    List.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I understand the difference, thanks for clarifying. I am aware of the untyped pointer as an argument for create thread but do you have an example of how to use this param of the same TStrings object? Passing Pointer(List) which is already created to the CreateThread is not the issue, accessing it within the worker thread however seems to be.

Comment: @WayOfTheWright "*do you have an example of how to use this param of the same TStrings object*" - do you not see the code I provided in my answer? Refresh the page if you need to. "*Passing Pointer(List) which is already created to the CreateThread is not the issue, accessing it within the worker thread however seems to be*" - simply cast the `Pointer` back to `TStrings`, how hard is that? Also, you don't need to *explicitly* cast `List` to `Pointer`, as it is already a pointer type, and all pointers are *implicitly* convertible to `Pointer`

Comment: TY I see it now, I'll give it a try after dinner and I truly appreciate it. Thanks Remy and Andreas for the solid advice here.

Comment: Works great, TY again for your time Remy as well as Andreas! You guys are awesome and your answers were perfectly concise and understandable to me. That means a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should use  platform independent function `BeginThread` which calls `CreateThread` internally.

here an example

https://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.php?Name=BeginThread

Comment: The questioner just wanted to know how to it for pure win32, so there’s no need to use a platform independent version.